# statsmodel attributes variable name

Tags: statsmodels

From the OLS Regression Summary results I am trying to find the attribute for the name of the variable.  From the below code I can get the p-value by olsres8.pvalues[9].  I am wanting to run a loop and sort the results after the summary runs and sort in descending order by pvalues looking for values over 0.05.  I am wanting to get for example the Seats_8D below.  I have printed all the attributes and tried each one.

```
olsmod8 = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train11)
olsres8 = olsmod8.fit()
print(olsres8.summary())

                          coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
```

---

const                    -199.1556      3.097    -64.307      0.000    -205.227    -193.084
Year                        0.1001      0.002     64.972      0.000       0.097       0.103
Mileage                    -0.0214      0.001    -15.328      0.000      -0.024      -0.019
Kilometers_Driven_z_std    -0.0231      0.005     -4.975      0.000      -0.032      -0.014
Power_z_std                 0.3948      0.007     58.662      0.000       0.382       0.408
Fuel_Type_Diesel            0.3204      0.010     32.269      0.000       0.301       0.340
Transmission_Manual        -0.2903      0.012    -24.233      0.000      -0.314      -0.267
Owner_Type_Second          -0.0483      0.012     -4.086      0.000      -0.071      -0.025
Seats_2D                    0.2651      0.090      2.937      0.003       0.088       0.442
Seats_8D                    0.0783      0.030      2.642      0.008       0.020       0.136

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the columns of `X` when `X` is a `DataFrame`. If `X` is not a `DataFrame`, but `y` is a `Series`, then you can use `olsreas8.params.index` to get the variable names.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

y_train = pd.Series(np.random.standard_normal(250))
X_train11 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((250,3)))
X_train11.columns = ["a","b","c_d"]
X_train11 = sm.add_constant(X_train11)

olsmod8 = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train11)
olsres8 = olsmod8.fit()
for column in X_train11:
    print(f"Variable: {column}, p-value: {olsres8.pvalues[column]:0.3f}")
```

This produces

```
Variable: const, p-value: 0.240195768864814
Variable: a, p-value: 0.7086889846554942
Variable: b, p-value: 0.6370054424161432
Variable: c_d, p-value: 0.5382060593843204
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get what I needed from above.